# In Scipy how and why does curve_fit calculate the covariance of the parameter estimates

Tags: python, scipy, curve

I have been using `scipy.optimize.leastsq` to fit some data. I would like to get some confidence intervals on these estimates so I look into the `cov_x` output but the documentation is very unclear as to what this is and how to get the covariance matrix for my parameters from this.

First of all it says that it is a Jacobian, but in the [notes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html) it also says that "`cov_x` is a Jacobian approximation to the Hessian" so that it is not actually a Jacobian but a Hessian using some approximation from the Jacobian. Which of these statements is correct?

Secondly this sentence to me is confusing:

> This matrix must be multiplied by the residual variance to get the covariance of the parameter estimates – see `curve_fit`.

I indeed go look at the source code for `curve_fit` where they do:

```
s_sq = (func(popt, *args)**2).sum()/(len(ydata)-len(p0))
pcov = pcov * s_sq
```

which corresponds to multiplying `cov_x` by `s_sq` but I cannot find this equation in any reference. Can someone explain why this equation is correct?
My intuition tells me that it should be the other way around since `cov_x` is supposed to be a derivative (Jacobian or Hessian) so I was thinking:
`cov_x * covariance(parameters) = sum of errors(residuals)` where `sigma(parameters)` is the thing I want.

How do I connect the thing curve_fit is doing with what I see at eg. wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Non-linear_combinations

Answer (score 32, accepted):

OK, I think I found the answer. First the solution:
cov_x*s_sq is simply the covariance of the parameters which is what you want. Taking sqrt of the diagonal elements will give you standard deviation (but be careful about covariances!).

Residual variance = reduced chi square = s_sq = sum[(f(x)-y)^2]/(N-n), where N is number of data points and n is the number of fitting parameters. [Reduced chi square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit).

The reason for my confusion is that cov_x as given by leastsq is not actually what is called cov(x) in other places rather it is the reduced cov(x) or fractional cov(x). The reason it does not show up in any of the other references is that it is a simple rescaling which is useful in numerical computations, but is not relevant for a textbook.

About Hessian versus Jacobian, the documentation is poorly worded. It is the Hessian that is calculated in both cases as is obvious since the Jacobian is zero at a minimum. What they mean is that they are using an approximation to the Jacobian to find the Hessian.

A further note. It seems that the curve_fit result does not actually account for the absolute size of the errors, but only take into account the relative size of the sigmas provided. This means that the pcov returned doesn't change even if the errorbars change by a factor of a million. This is of course not right, but seems to be standard practice ie. Matlab does the same thing when using their Curve fitting toolbox. The correct procedure is described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Parameter_errors_and_correlation

It seems fairly straightforward to do this once the optimum has been found, at least for Linear Least squares.

Comment: The formula for chi-square should be multiplied by 1.0 / errors^2, I think?

Comment: “It seems that the curve_fit result does not actually account for the absolute size of the errors, but only take into account the relative size of the sigmas provided.”  There is a flag for this: `absolute_sigma`. If it's off (default), then `curve_fit` will estimate the var(y) based on your data; otherwise, it will take use your provided `sigma` values.

Answer (score 7):

I found this solution during my search for a similar question, and I have only a small improvement on HansHarhoff's answer.  The full output from leastsq provides a return value infodict, which contains infodict['fvec'] =  f(x) -y.  Thus, to compute the reduced chi square =  (in the above notation)

`s_sq = (infodict['fvec']**2).sum()/ (N-n)`

BTW.  Thanks HansHarhoff for doing most of the heavy lifting to solve this.

Comment: Very nice! Exactly what I was looking for.

Specificially:
`result=scipy.optimize.leastsq(...,, full_output=True);s_sq = (result]['fvec']**2).sum()/(len(result[2]['fvec'])-len(result[0]))`

Comment: what version do you have to support the `full_output`?

Comment: I don't know what the minimum version would be to support the `full_output` option, but I use scipy 0.13.3 and 0.14.1.

Comment: @CharlesPlager you are missing a `[2` there ... `s_sq = (result[2]['fvec']**2).sum()/(len(result[2]['fvec'])-len(result[0]))`

Answer (score 7):

### Math

First we start with linear regression. In many statistical problems, we assume the variables have some underlying distributions with some unknown parameters and we estimate these parameters. In linear regression, we assume the dependent variables y<sub>i</sub> have a linear relationship with the independent variables x<sub>ij</sub>:

y<sub>i</sub> = x<sub>i1</sub>β<sub>1</sub> + ... + x<sub>ip</sub>β<sub>p</sub> + σε<sub>i</sub>, i = 1, ..., n.

where ε<sub>i</sub> has independent standard normal distribution, β<sub>j</sub>'s are p unknown parameters and σ is also unknown. We can write this in matrix form:

Y = X β + σε,

where Y, β, and ε is a column vector. To find the best β, we minimize the sum of the squares

S = (Y - X β)<sup>T</sup> (Y - X β).

I just write out the solution, which is

β^ = (X<sup>T</sup> X)<sup>-1</sup> X<sup>T</sup> Y.

If we see Y as the specific observed data, β^ is the estimation of β under that observation. On the other hand, if we see Y as the random variable, the estimator β^ becomes a random variable too. In this way, we can see what the covariance of β^ is.

Because Y has a multivariate normal distribution and β^ is a linear transformation of Y, β^ has also a multivariate normal distribution. The covariance matrix of β^ is

Cov(β^) = (X<sup>T</sup> X)<sup>-1</sup> X<sup>T</sup> Cov(Y) ((X<sup>T</sup> X)<sup>-1</sup> X<sup>T</sup>)<sup>T</sup> = (X <sup>T</sup> X)<sup>-1</sup> σ<sup>2</sup>.

But here σ is unknown, so we also need to estimate it. If we let

Q = (Y - X β^)<sup>T</sup> (Y - X β^),

it can be proved that Q / σ<sup>2</sup> has the chi-square distribution with n - p degrees of freedom (moreover, Q is independent of β^). This makes

σ^<sup>2</sup> = Q / (n - p)

an unbiased estimator of σ<sup>2</sup>. So the final estimator of Cov(β^) is

(X<sup>T</sup> X)<sup>-1</sup> Q / (n - p).

### SciPy API

`curve_fit` is the most convenient, the second return value `pcov` is just the estimation of the covariance of β^, that is the final result (X<sup>T</sup> X)<sup>-1</sup> Q / (n - p) above.

In `leastsq`, the second return value `cov_x` is (X<sup>T</sup> X)<sup>-1</sup>. From the expression of S, we see X<sup>T</sup> X is the Hessian of S (half of the Hessian, to be precise), that's why the document says `cov_x` is the inverse of the Hessian. To get the covariance, you need to multiply `cov_x` with Q / (n - p).

### Non-Linear Regression

In non-linear regression, y<sub>i</sub> depend on the parameters non-linearly:

y<sub>i</sub> = f(**x**<sub>i</sub>, β<sub>1</sub>, ... , β<sub>p</sub>) + σε<sub>i</sub>.

We can calculate the partial derivatives of f with respect to β<sub>j</sub>, so it becomes approximately linear. Then the calculation is basically the same as linear regression except we need to approximate the minimum iteratively. In practice, the algorithm can be some more sophisticated one such as the Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm which is the default of `curve_fit`.

### More About Providing Sigma

This section is about the `sigma` and `absolute_sigma` parameter in `curve_fit`. For basic usage of `curve_fit` when you have no prior knowledge about the covariance of Y, you can ignore this section.

#### Absolute Sigma

In linear regression above, the variance of y<sub>i</sub> is σ and is unknown. If you know the variance. You can provide it to `curve_fit` through the `sigma` parameter and set `absolute_sigma=True`.

Suppose your provided `sigma` matrix is Σ. i.e.

Y ~ N(X β, Σ).

Y has the multivariate normal distribution with mean X β and covariance Σ. We want to maximize the likelihood of Y. From probability density function of Y, that is equivalent to minimize

S = (Y - X β)<sup>T</sup> Σ<sup>-1</sup> (Y - X β).

The solution is

β^ = (X<sup>T</sup> Σ<sup>-1</sup> X)<sup>-1</sup> X<sup>T</sup> Σ<sup>-1</sup> Y.

And

Cov(β^) = (X<sup>T</sup> Σ<sup>-1</sup> X)<sup>-1</sup>.

The β^ and Cov(β^) above are the return values of `curve_fit` with `absolute_sigma=True`.

#### Relative Sigma

In some cases, you don't know the exact variance of y<sub>i</sub>, but you know the relative relationship between different y<sub>i</sub>, for example the variance of y<sub>2</sub> is 4 times the variance of y<sub>1</sub>. Then you can pass `sigma` and set `absolute_sigma=False`.

This time

Y ~ N(X β, Σσ)

with a known matrix Σ provided and an unknown number σ. The objective function to minimize is the same as absolute sigma since σ is a constant, and thus the estimator β^ is the same. But the covariance

Cov(β^) = (X<sup>T</sup> Σ<sup>-1</sup> X)<sup>-1</sup> σ<sup>2</sup>,

has the unknown σ in it. To estimate σ, let

Q = (Y - X β^)<sup>T</sup> Σ<sup>-1</sup> (Y - X β^).

Again, Q / σ<sup>2</sup> has the chi-square distribution with n - p degrees of freedom.

The estimation of Cov(β^) is

(X<sup>T</sup> Σ<sup>-1</sup> X)<sup>-1</sup> Q / (n - p).

And this is the second return value of `curve_fit` with `absolute_sigma=False`.