# Errors on a Gaussian histogram curve fit using scipy.curve_fit()

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to get the fit errors of a Gaussian fit of a histogram.  I am using *scipy.optimize.curve_fit* in the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt 
from pylab import exp
import numpy as np 
from scipy import optimize
from math import sqrt

# Fit functions
def Gaussian(x,a,b,c):
    return a * exp(-(x - b)**2.0 / (2 * c**2))

# Generate data from random Guassian distribution
npix = 10200
nbins = int(sqrt(npix))
data = np.random.standard_normal(npix)
print('\n Length of y: %s' % len(data))
n,bins,patches = plt.hist(data,bins=nbins)

# Generate data from bins as a set of points 
bin_size = abs(bins[1]-bins[0])
x =np.linspace(start=bins[0]+bin_size/2.0,stop=bins[-2]+bin_size/2.0,\
num=nbins,endpoint=True)
print min(x),max(x),len(x), np.mean(x)
y = n
y[y==0]= 1e-8


popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(Gaussian,x,y) 

# Curve-fit error method
error = [] 
for i in range(len(popt)):
    try:
      error.append( np.absolute(pcov[i][i])**0.5)
    except:
      error.append( 0.00 )
pfit_curvefit = popt
perr_curvefit = np.array(error) 
print('\n Curve-fit Curve fit: %s' % pfit_curvefit)
print('\n Curve-fit Fit errors: %s' % perr_curvefit)

# Plot the fit
x_fit = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], nbins)
y_gauss = Gaussian(x_fit, *popt)
# y_boot = Gaussian(x_fit, *pfit_bootstrap)
yerr=Gaussian(x_fit,*perr_curvefit)

plt.plot(x_fit, y_gauss,linestyle='--',linewidth=2,\
color='red',label='Gaussian')



plt.xlabel('Pixel Values')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Npix = %s, Nbins = %s'% (npix,nbins))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see, I can get Python to adequately fit the histogram data no problem.  The problem arises when I try to compute the fit error

yerr=Gaussian(x_fit,*perr_curvefit)

This seems like it would be the right thing to do, however when I look at this list of errors it looks non-sensical:

> ...
>   0.0
>   0.0
>   0.0
>   0.0
>   0.0
>   2.60905702842e-265
>   2.27384038589e-155
>   1.02313435685e-74
>   2.37684931814e-23
>   0.285080112094
>   1.76534048255e-08
>   5.64399121475e-45
>   9.31623567809e-111
>   7.93945868459e-206
>   0.0
>   0.0
>   0.0
>   0.0
>   0.0
>   ...

My questions are:
1. Were the errors in the fit computed correctly, and if not, what would be the correct way to compute them. 
2. I need the errors in the fit to compute a reduced chi-squared value.  Is there another way I can compute chi-squared without having to know the error at each point in the fit?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The good way to compute the error is yerr=(Gaussian(x_fit,*popt)-y) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main error is the calculation of the error values.  Your array `error` is asymptotic estimate of the standard deviations for the coefficients `a,b,c` in the function `Gaussian`. You can't then input a value x and uncertainty +/-a, +/-b, +/-c and get meaningful results, because the error is about the mean of a,b & c, i.e., Gaussian(x, a+/- delta a, etc.)

If you are not wedded to the use of `optimize.curve_fit()` and would use `optimize.leastsq()`, the information you want is readily available.
See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854339/in-scipy-how-and-why-does-curve-fit-calculate-the-covariance-of-the-parameter-es/17508924#17508924)

replace

```
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(Gaussian,x,y)
```

with

```
def residual(p, x, y):
    return Gaussian(x, *p) - y

initGuess = [1,1,1] # or whatever you want the search to start at
popt, pcov, infodict, mesg, ier = optimize.least_squares(residual,initGuess, args=[x,y], full_output=True)
```

and then follow the instructions in the solution to find the reduced chi square

```
s_sq = (infodict['fvec']**2).sum()/ (N-n)
```