# How to obtain chi squared value from scipy least_squares function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, least-squares, chi-squared

I am using the least_squares function from scipy http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html to fit a model to some data that I took, and obtain a value for the parameters in the model.  I would like to also get a chi squared value for the model.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: I think this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854339/in-scipy-how-and-why-does-curve-fit-calculate-the-covariance-of-the-parameter-es/17508924#17508924