# Finding minima of curve inside curve_fit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

Summary:
I have a function I want to put through curve_fit that is piecewise, but whose pieces do not have a clean analytical form.  I've gotten the process to work by including a somewhat janky `for` loop, but it runs pretty slowly: 1-2 minutes for relatively sets of data with N=10,000.  I'm hoping for advice on how to (a) use numpy broadcasting to speed up the operation (no `for` loop) or (b) do something totally differently that gets the same type of results, but much faster.

The function `z=f(x,y; params)` I'm working with is piecewise, monotonically increasing in `y` until it reaches the maximum value of `f`, at point `y_0`, and then saturates and becomes constant. My problem is that the break-point `y_0` is not analytic, so requires some optimization.  This would be relatively easy, except that I have real data in both `x` and `y`, and the break-point is a function of the fitting parameter `c`.  All the data, `x`, `y`, and `z` have instrumentation noise.

Example problem:
The function below has been changed to make it easier to illustrate the problem I'm trying to deal with. *Yes, I realize it is analytically solvable, but my real problem is **not.***

```
f(x,y; c) = 
    y*(x-c*y),    for y <= x/(2*c)
    x**2/(4*c),   for y >  x/(2*c)
```

The break-point `y_0 = x/(2*c)` is found by taking the derivative of `f` WRT `y` and solving for the maximum.  The maximum `f_max=x**2/(4*c)` is found by putting `y_0` back into `f`.  The problem is is that the break-point is dependent on both the `x`-value and the fitting parameter `c`, so I can't compute the breakpoint outside the internal loop.

Code
I have reduced the number of points to ~500 points to allow the code to run in a reasonable amount of time.  My real data has >10,000 points.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit,fminbound
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def function((x,y),c=1):

    fxn_xy = lambda x,y: y*(x-c*y)

    y_max = np.zeros(len(x))    #create array in which to put max values of y
    fxn_max = np.zeros(len(x))  #array to put the results 

    '''This loop is the first part I'd like to optimize, since it requires 
    O(1/delta) time for each individual pass through the fitting function'''

    for i,X in enumerate(x):
        '''X represents specific value of x to solve for'''        

        fxn_y = lambda y: fxn_xy(X,y)  
        #reduce function to just one variable (y)
        #by inputting given X value for the loop

        max_y = fminbound(lambda Y: -fxn_y(Y), 0, X, full_output=True)
        y_max[i] = max_y[0]
        fxn_max[i] = -max_y[1]

    return np.where(y<=y_max,
        fxn_xy(x,y),
        fxn_max
        )


'''  Create and plot 'real' data   '''
delta = 0.01
xs = [0.5,1.,1.5,2.]  #num copies of each X value

y = []

#create repeated x for each xs value.  +1 used to match size of y, below
x = np.hstack([X]*(int(X//delta+1)) for X in xs)
#create sweep from 1 to the current value of x, with spacing=delta
y = np.hstack([np.arange(0, X, delta) for X in xs]) 
z = function((x,y),c=0.75)

#introduce random instrumentation noise to x,y,z
x += np.random.normal(0,0.005,size=len(x))
y += np.random.normal(0,0.005,size=len(y))  
z += np.random.normal(0,0.05,size=len(z))


fig = plt.figure(1,(12,8))
axis1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
axis2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

axis1.scatter(y,x,s=1)
#axis1.plot(x)
#axis1.plot(z)
axis1.set_ylabel("x value")
axis1.set_xlabel("y value")

axis2.scatter(y,z, s=1)
axis2.set_xlabel("y value")
axis2.set_ylabel("z(x,y)")



'''Curve Fitting process to find optimal c'''
popt, pcov = curve_fit(function, (x,y),z,bounds=(0,2))
axis2.scatter(y, function((x,y),*popt), s=0.5, c='r')

print "c_est = {:.3g} ".format(popt[0])
```

The results are plotted below, with "real" x,y,z values (blue) and fitted values (red).
[image]

Notes: my intuition is figuring out how to broadcast the `x` variable s.t. I can use it in fminbound.  But that may be naive.  Thoughts?

Thanks everybody!

Edit: to clarify, the `x`-values are not always fixed in groups like that and could instead be swept as the `y`-values are held steady. Which is unfortunately why I need some way of dealing with `x` so many times.

Comment: Might you find y_0 by first fitting every 50th data point for an estimate, and then refine the estimate by fitting all data within 100 data points on each side of the estimate, and then knowing the actual y_0 use that for fitting all of the data?

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely follow what you mean.  Can you elaborate, and possibly give an idea of how that would fit into curve_fit?

Comment: My suggestion is to first estimate y_0, second refine that estimate to actual value, third fit using that now-known value of y_0 as a constant when fitting. If this works it should reduce the total fitting time.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that can be optimised. One problem is the data structure. If I understand the code correctly, you look for the `max` for all `x`. However, you made the structure such that the same values are repeated over and over again. Hence, here you waste a lot of computational effort.

I am not sure how difficult the evaluation of `f` is in reality, but I assume that it is not significantly more costly than the optimization. So in my solution I just calculate the full array, look for the maximum, and change the values coming afterwards.

I guess my code can be optimized as well, but right now it looks like:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def function( yArray, x=1, c=1 ):
    out = np.fromiter( ( y * ( x - c * y ) for y in yArray ), np.float )
    pos = np.argmax( out )
    outMax = out[ pos ]
    return np.fromiter( ( x if i < pos else outMax for i, x in enumerate( out ) ), np.float )


def residuals( param, xArray, yList, zList ):
    c = param
    zListTheory = [ function( yArray, x=X, c=c ) for yArray, X in zip( yList, xArray ) ]
    diffList = [ zArray - zArrayTheory for zArray, zArrayTheory in zip( zList, zListTheory ) ]
    out = [ item  for diffArray in diffList for item in diffArray ]
    return out


'''  Create and plot 'real' data   '''
delta = 0.01
xArray = np.array( [ 0.5, 1., 1.5, 2. ] )  #keep this as parameter
#create sweep from 1 to the current value of x, with spacing=delta
yList = [ np.arange( 0, X, delta ) for X in xArray ] ## as list of arrays
zList = [ function( yArray, x=X, c=0.75 ) for yArray, X in zip( yList, xArray ) ]


fig = plt.figure( 1, ( 12, 8 ) )
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )
for y,z in zip( yList, zList ):
    ax.plot( y, z )

#introduce random instrumentation noise
yRList =[ yArray + np.random.normal( 0, 0.02, size=len( yArray ) ) for yArray in yList ]
zRList =[ zArray + np.random.normal( 0, 0.02, size=len( zArray ) ) for zArray in zList ]

ax.set_prop_cycle( None )
for y,z in zip( yRList, zRList ):
    ax.plot( y, z, marker='o', markersize=2, ls='' )

sol, cov, info, msg, ier = leastsq( residuals, x0=.9, args=( xArray, yRList, zRList ), full_output=True )
print "c_est = {:.3g} ".format( sol[0] )
plt.show()
```

providing

```
>> c_est = 0.752
```

With the original graphs and noisy data being
[image: Theory and Data]

Comment: This looks like a good answer, and thank you for the effort!  I'm still working through it and will probably ask more questions later.  The one detail about the data structure is that all data comes from the sensors in triplets of `(x,y,z)`, so `x` is also noisy, slightly variable on its own, and not guaranteed to always come in the groups listed (for example, I could hold `y` relatively steady and sweep `x` instead).

Comment: @Necarion OK I see the point concerning `x`. The problem with your `curve_fit` and my `leastsq` then is that they only optimize errors in `z` assuming no error in `x` or `y`. In case you can fix `x` to some average you may use `ODR` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46904786/803359). Otherwise, one has to generalize this to an ellipsoid touching a surface. Concerning speed of the algorithm, this definitively goes in the wrong direction, though. If on the other hand errors in `x`, `y`, and `z` are of equal order, that's probably the way to go.