# Covariance numbers from Jacobian Matrix in scipy.optimize.least_squares

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, least-squares, scipy-optimize

I wanted to fit a logistic curve to some data.
I used the general equation of the logistic curve to fit to my data. Find it [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function).

```
def generate_data(t, A, K, C, Q, B, v):

    y = A+ (K-A)*((C+Q*np.exp(-B*t))**(1/v))

    return y
```

Here A, K, C, Q, B and v were variables I wanted to find.

I used the `scipy.optimize.least_squares` function to get the values to generate my curve.

This was the argument function.

```
def fun(x, t, y):
    return x[0] + (x[1]-x[0])*((x[2]+x[3]*np.exp(-x[4]*t))**(1/x[5])) - y
```

And this is how I called he actual optimisation function.

```
res_lsq= least_squares(fun, x0, args=(x_coord, y_coord))
```

Visually, the curve fit the data excellently.
[image]

I then calculated the Covariance matrix by this method.

```
J = res_lsq.jac
cov = np.linalg.inv(J.T.dot(J))
```

And then the variance using this method.

```
var = np.sqrt(np.diagonal(cov))
```

The problem is that for these were the values for my parameters.

```
Parameters= [ 1.94624122  5.66832958  5.21005677 -4.87025481  0.02520876  0.15057123 ]
```

And these were my variance values.

```
Variance= [3.38436210e-01 3.94262000e+03 8.30968350e+02 7.76773161e+02
 6.44604446e-05 6.49474460e-04]
```

One value is 3942 for a parameter rhat is 5.66
What do these values mean? Does this data actually show how well the curve fits the data? How do I get such a quantity, like an analogue to a p-value etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue.

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854339/in-scipy-how-and-why-does-curve-fit-calculate-the-covariance-of-the-parameter-es).

There they explain that you need to multiply the `cov` that you mentioned by the Mean Squared Error, that is ``sum[(f(x)-y)^2]/(N-n)```, where N is the length of the data and n is the number of parameters you are fitting. It will probably yield a small number and your variance will probably reduce.

All the best,

Murilo