# Two parameter non-linear function for modeling a 3-D surface

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, curve-fitting, statsmodels

I'm interested in modeling this surface with a simple equation that takes in two parameters (x,y) values and produces a z value. Ideally an equation that has a simple form. I have tried Monkey Saddle, polynomial regression (3rd and 4th order) and also multi-linear and log-linear OLS with some success (R^2 0.99), but none that are perfect especially for the curvy part. It seems like there should be a simple model to predict this surface. Maybe a non-linear regression method. Any suggestions? Thanks!
[image: Z-axis is the predictand, and the other two are predictors]

Using Mikuszefski's suggestion seems to produce a reasonable result for the curvy bit:
[image: Predicted points from 5 methods]

Comment: Uh...this is likely to be closed, but FWIW: Hard to say without having the data or knowing where it comes from. I would give something like ` ( a * x**p *( b + ( y - c * x  - d)**(-q) ) )` a try. Root like behavior in `x` and shifted divergence in `y`. Probably over-fitting with 6 parameters, though.

Comment: Thanks, Mikuszefski! Yes, this worked better than other methods for capturing the curvy bit. But, overall, I am still not able to get a better performance than 4th order polynomial regression.

Comment: Well, I'd say that a polynomial fit is only good for data with smooth curvature (not flat and not too steep). But as I said above, without knowing where the data comes from and without having access to play around, it's hard to say more.

Comment: The data is here if you want to poke around. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cX6rHUDZXKBjozYPTRVmzIazgmmc3hwz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: A comment on the 4th order polynomial fit. That has quite a large number of free parameters, which are likely not justified. Of course a fit is getting better the more parameters you have, so check the reduced chi-square for overfitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the OP is problematic in the sense that it is not really a programming question, here my try to fit the data with a function that has a reasonable small amount of parameters, i.e. 6. The code somehow shows my line of thinking in retrieving this solution. It fits the data very well, but probably has no physical meaning whatsoever.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d


import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions( precision=3 )
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

data0 = np.loadtxt( "XYZ.csv", delimiter=",")
data = data0.reshape(11,16,4)
tdata = np.transpose(data, axes=(1,0,2))

### first guess for the shape of the data when plotted against x
def my_p( x, a, p):
    return a * x**p

### turns out that the fit parameters theselve follow the above law
### themselve but with an offset and plotted against z, of course
def my_p2( x, a, p, x0):
    return a * (x - x0)**p

def my_full( x, y, asc, aexp, ash, psc, pexp, psh):
    a = my_p2( y, asc, aexp, ash )
    p = my_p2( y, psc, pexp, psh )
    z = my_p( x, a, p)
    return z


### base lists for plotting
xl = np.linspace( 0, 30, 150 )
yl = np.linspace( 5, 200, 200 )


### setting the plots
fig = plt.figure( figsize=( 16, 12) )
ax = fig.add_subplot( 2, 3, 1 )
bx = fig.add_subplot( 2, 3, 2 )
cx = fig.add_subplot( 2, 3, 3 )
dx = fig.add_subplot( 2, 3, 4 )
ex = fig.add_subplot( 2, 3, 5 )
fx = fig.add_subplot( 2, 3, 6, projection='3d' )


### fitting the data linewise for different z as function of x
### keeping track of the fit parameters
adata = list()
pdata = list()
for subdata in data:
    xdata = subdata[::,1]
    zdata = subdata[::,3 ] 
    sol,_ = curve_fit( my_p, xdata, zdata )
    print( sol, subdata[0,2] ) ### fit parameters for different z
    adata.append( [subdata[0,2] , sol[0] ] )
    pdata.append( [subdata[0,2] , sol[1] ] )
    ### plotting the z-cuts
    ax.plot( xdata , zdata , ls='', marker='o')
    ax.plot( xl, my_p( xl, *sol ) )

adata = np.array( adata )
pdata = np.array( pdata )

ax.scatter( [0],[0] )
ax.grid()

### fitting the the fitparameters as function of z 
sola, _ = curve_fit( my_p2, adata[::,0], adata[::,1], p0= ( 1, -0.05,0 ) )
print( sola )
bx.plot( *(adata.transpose() ) )
bx.plot( yl, my_p2( yl,  *sola))

solp, _ = curve_fit( my_p2, pdata[::,0], pdata[::,1], p0= ( 1, -0.05,0 ) )
print( solp )
cx.plot( *(pdata.transpose() ) )
cx.plot( yl, my_p2( yl,  *solp))

### plotting the cuts applying the resuts from the "fit of fits"
for subdata in data:
    xdata = subdata[ ::, 1 ]
    y0 = subdata[ 0, 2 ]
    zdata = subdata[ ::, 3 ]
    dx.plot( xdata , zdata , ls='', marker='o' )
    dx.plot(
        xl,
        my_full(
            xl, y0, 2.12478827, -0.187, -20.84, 0.928, -0.0468, 0.678
        )
    )

### now fitting the entire data with the overall 6 parameter function 
def residuals( params, alldata ):
    asc, aexp, ash, psc, pexp, psh = params
    diff = list()
    for data in alldata:
        x = data[1]
        y = data[2]
        z = data[3]
        zth = my_full( x, y, asc, aexp, ash, psc, pexp, psh)
        diff.append( z - zth )
    return diff

## and fitting using the hand-made residual function and least_squares
resultfinal = least_squares(
    residuals, 
    x0 =( 2.12478827, -0.187, -20.84, 0.928, -0.0468, 0.678 ),
    args = ( data0, ) )

### least_squares does not provide errors but the approximated jacobian
### so we follow:
### https://stackoverflow.com/q/61459040/803359
### https://stackoverflow.com/q/14854339/803359
print( resultfinal.x)
resi = resultfinal.fun
JMX = resultfinal.jac
HMX = np.dot( JMX.transpose(),JMX )
cov_red = np.linalg.inv( HMX )
s_sq = np.sum( resi**2 ) /( len(data0) - 6 )
cov = cov_red * s_sq

print( cov )

### plotting the cuts with the overall fit
for subdata in data:
    xdata = subdata[::,1]
    y0 = subdata[0,2]
    zdata = subdata[::,3 ] 
    ex.plot( xdata , zdata , ls='', marker='o')
    ex.plot( xl, my_full( xl, y0, *resultfinal.x ) )

### and in 3d, which is actually not very helpful partially due to the
### fact that matplotlib has limited 3d capabilities.
XX, YY = np.meshgrid( xl, yl )
ZZ = my_full( XX, YY, *resultfinal.x )
fx.scatter(
    data0[::,1], data0[::,2], data0[::,3],
    color="#ff0000", alpha=1 )
fx.plot_wireframe( XX, YY, ZZ , cmap='inferno')

plt.show()
```

Providing

```py
[1.154 0.866] 5.0
[1.126 0.837] 10.0
[1.076 0.802] 20.0
[1.013 0.794] 30.0
[0.975 0.789] 40.0
[0.961 0.771] 50.0
[0.919 0.754] 75.0
[0.86  0.748] 100.0
[0.845 0.738] 125.0
[0.816 0.735] 150.0
[0.774 0.726] 200.0

[  2.125  -0.186 -20.841]
[ 0.928 -0.047  0.678]

[  1.874  -0.162 -13.83    0.949  -0.052  -1.228]

[[ 6.851e-03 -7.413e-04 -1.737e-01 -6.914e-04  1.638e-04  5.367e-02]
 [-7.413e-04  8.293e-05  1.729e-02  8.103e-05 -2.019e-05 -5.816e-03]
 [-1.737e-01  1.729e-02  5.961e+00  1.140e-02 -2.272e-03 -1.423e+00]
 [-6.914e-04  8.103e-05  1.140e-02  1.050e-04 -2.672e-05 -6.100e-03]
 [ 1.638e-04 -2.019e-05 -2.272e-03 -2.672e-05  7.164e-06  1.455e-03]
 [ 5.367e-02 -5.816e-03 -1.423e+00 -6.100e-03  1.455e-03  5.090e-01]]
```

and

[image: Fitting the data with a strange function]

The fit looks good and the covariance matrix seems also ok.
The final function, hence, is:

`z = 1.874 / ( y + 13.83 )**0.162 * x**(  0.949 / ( y + 1.228 )**0.052 )`

Comment: Thank you! Looks good! Is there a quick way to convert the final function in terms of z=f(x,y)? I tried doing it in Wolfram Alpha, but it doesn't do it.

Comment: Oh...sorry. Don't know why I called it `z`, it is of course `y`; so that is actually `z = f(x,y)`

Comment: Thanks, Mikuszefski! I'm using this final function in a paper and acknowledging you there!

Comment: Right, that's fun (check the linkedIn on my profile for full name). Send me a copy if it gets accepted. Note though, that the only motivation for this function is that it looks good and has a reasonable small amount of parameters.

Comment: Yes, got your full name! I will remember to send you the paper if it gets accepted. If you're curious, the data is: X=wind speed at height H, Y=height H, Z is wind speed at ground level (1 foot above surface). The paper is about the forgotten works on lake evaporation by Robert E. Horton - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_E._Horton. Thanks for taking the time! Great work!

Comment: Wow, ok. Sounds more like one should fit `x` as a function of `y` and `z`. BTW, I think the shift for `p` could be omitted. It is not really justified in the sense of a reduced chi^2. which only changes from `0.00595` to `0.00608` giving `z = 2.028 / ( y + 17.38 )**0.178 * x**(  0.933 / y**0.048 )` as a very nice five-parameter fit.

Comment: I just remembered that you asked for the paper when it is published. It got published with positive reviewers' comments in an open access journal. You can read the full paper here - https://hess.copernicus.org/articles/26/445/2022/. Duly acknowledged your contribution in the Acknowledgments section. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty cool. Congrats for the nice publication.