# Goodness of fit in PSF photometry with photutils BasicPSFPhotometry

Tags: python, python-3.x, least-squares, chi-squared, photutils

I'm using BasicPSFPhotometry from photutils.psf to obtain the photometry of a source.

Here an example of my code (sadly is not a working example but can help understanding what I'm doing and what I need). Most of this was copied from https://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/psf.html and adapted to my needs.

```
fitter=LevMarLSQFitter()
psf_model = photutils.psf.FittableImageModel(psfdata,normalize=True)
pos = Table(names=['id','x_0', 'y_0','flux_0'], data=[[1],[xycen[0]],[xycen[1]],[flux]])

photometrypsf = BasicPSFPhotometry(group_maker=daogroup,
                                    bkg_estimator=None,
                                    psf_model=psf_model,
                                    fitter=fitter,
                                    fitshape=target.shape,
                                    aperture_radius=fwhm)

psf_photometry = photometrypsf(image=target.copy(),init_guesses=pos)
```

I need to estimate the chi square for the PSF fitting of my source but I don't understand how to do it.

I was following this post ([In Scipy how and why does curve_fit calculate the covariance of the parameter estimates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14854339/in-scipy-how-and-why-does-curve-fit-calculate-the-covariance-of-the-parameter-es/17508924#17508924)) where they explain how to get a reduced chi squared as:

```
s_sq = (infodict['fvec']**2).sum()/ (N-n)
```

that I was able to translate i  my code in:

```
s_sq = (fitter.fit_info['fvec']**2).sum()/(len(fitter.fit_info['fvec'])-n)
```

The problem is that I don't know how to evaluate "n". In the example they say n (number of free parameter) is the length of the output x of *scipy.optimize.leastsq* (the first output) but *LevMarLSQFitter* clearly state that:

> Note that the x return value is not included (as it is instead the
> parameter values of the returned model).

So the question is, using *LevMarLSQFitter* in conjunction with *BasicPSFPhotometry* what is the most practical way to estimate the chi square for the fit (or any other parameter can let me understand the goodness of the fit)? Moreover, how do I acces to the parameter of the fit performed from *LevMarLSQFitter*?