# Print 'std err' value from statsmodels OLS results

Tags: python, io, statsmodels

(Sorry to ask but http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/ is currently down and I can't access the docs)

I'm doing a linear regression using `statsmodels`, basically:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
model = sm.OLS(y,x)
results = model.fit()
```

I know that I can print out the full set of results with:

```
print results.summary()
```

which outputs something like:

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.952
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.951
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     972.9
Date:                Mon, 20 Jul 2015   Prob (F-statistic):           5.55e-34
Time:                        15:35:22   Log-Likelihood:                -78.843
No. Observations:                  50   AIC:                             159.7
Df Residuals:                      49   BIC:                             161.6
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x1             1.0250      0.033     31.191      0.000         0.959     1.091
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       16.396   Durbin-Watson:                   2.166
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):                3.480
Skew:                          -0.082   Prob(JB):                        0.175
Kurtosis:                       1.718   Cond. No.                         1.00
==============================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
```

I need a way to print out *only*  the values of `coef` and `std err`.

I can access `coef` with:

```
print results.params
```

but I've found no way to print out `std err`.

How can I do this?

Comment: For now temporary, but most likely permanent replacement for the documentation on sourceforge is here http://statsmodels.github.io/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html

Comment: Didn't know that, thank you!

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Applying the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/192184/1391441) I used [dir()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) to print all the attributes of the `results` object.

After that I searched for the one that contained the `std err` value and it turned out to be:

```
print results.bse
```

(Not sure what the `b` stands for in `bse`, but I guess the `se` stands for "standard error")

Comment: The `b` is a historical artifact, when `params` where called `b` as in linear model `y = X b + u`, and should be properly called `params_se`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @user333700!

Comment: @Josef Do you mean `results.params_se`. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It’s still called ”bse” as in the answer. The name was never changed.

Answer (score 8):

`results.bse` provides standard errors for the coefficients, identical to those listed in `results.summary()`.

The standard error of the regression is obtained using `results.scale**.5`.

Also identical to `np.sqrt(np.sum(results.resid**2)/results.df_resid)`, where results is your fitted model.

Answer (score 1):

statistically standard error of estimate is always equal to square root of mean square error of residual. It can be obtained from results using the formula `np.sqrt(results.mse_resid)`

Comment: The question is for standard errors of parameter estimates, not for residual standard error.

Answer (score 0):

The following function can be used to get an overview of the regression analysis result. The parameter `ols_model` is the regression model generated by `statsmodels.formula.api`. The output is a pandas data frame saving the regression coefficient, standard errors, p values, number of observations, AIC, and adjusted rsquared. The standard errors are saved in brackets. `***`, `**`, and `*` represent 0.001, 0.01, 0.1 significance level:

```
def output_regres_result(ols_model, variable_list: list):
    """
    Create a pandas dataframe saving the regression analysis result
    :param ols_model: a linear model containing the regression result.
    type: statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResultsWrapper
    :param variable_list: a list of interested variable names
    :return: a pandas dataframe saving the regression coefficient, pvalues, standard errors, aic,
    number of observations, adjusted r squared
    """
    coef_dict = ols_model.params.to_dict()  # coefficient dictionary
    pval_dict = ols_model.pvalues.to_dict()  # pvalues dictionary
    std_error_dict = ols_model.bse.to_dict()  # standard error dictionary
    num_observs = np.int(ols_model.nobs) # number of observations
    aic_val = round(ols_model.aic, 2) # aic value
    adj_rsqured = round(ols_model.rsquared_adj, 3) # adjusted rsqured
    info_index = ['Num', 'AIC', 'Adjusted R2']
    index_list = variable_list + info_index

    for variable in variable_list:
        assert variable in coef_dict, 'Something wrong with variable name!'

    coef_vals = []

    for variable in variable_list:
        std_val = std_error_dict[variable]
        coef_val = coef_dict[variable]
        p_val = pval_dict[variable]
        if p_val <= 0.01:
            coef_vals.append('{}***({})'.format(round(coef_val, 4), round(std_val, 3)))
        elif 0.01 < p_val <= 0.05:
            coef_vals.append('{}**({})'.format(round(coef_val, 4), round(std_val, 3)))
        elif 0.05 < p_val <= 0.1:
            coef_vals.append('{}*({})'.format(round(coef_val, 4), round(std_val, 3)))
        else:
            coef_vals.append('{}({})'.format(round(coef_val, 4), round(std_val, 3)))

    coef_vals.extend([num_observs, aic_val, adj_rsqured])

    result_data = pd.DataFrame()
    result_data['coef'] = coef_vals
    result_data_reindex = result_data.set_index(pd.Index(index_list))

    return result_data_reindex
```

Comment: @ Bright Chang, it throws error:   ```AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_dict'```

Answer (score 0):

I like Topchi's method but an identical result can be pulled with slightly less code. This is for residual standard error, rather than standard errors of parameter estimates which others have already shared in the thread :)

```
np.sqrt(results.scale)
```