# Using Statsmodel and the ARIMA model to forecast but running into issues

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, statsmodels, arima

I'm trying to learn how to forecast data based on the ARIMA model that is in the library Statsmodel, but I keep running into issues. Currently i'm just trying to line up my prediction next to the actual to test my model but i cant get the ARIMA model results to cooperate

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

model = sm.tsa.arima.ARIMA(train, order=(4,1,2))
result = model.fit()

result.summary()

step = 10

fc, se, conf = result.forecast(step)
```

This all works but the last step is throwing this error

```
 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [57], in <module>
      1 step = 10
----> 3 fc, se, conf = result.forecast(step)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

I've been reading the documentation for hours but I cant get anywhere with it. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi, did you look at `help(result.forecast)`? It says it returns the mean of the predicted values (and only those). So it returns 1 thing but you expect 3 things, hence the error. I guess `fc` means "forecasts", right? Then `fc = result.forecast(step)` directly. `conf` is confidence intervals? Then you get that by `conf = result.get_forecast(step).conf_int()` (I agree that API is somewhat unintuitive). Not sure what `se` means. (standard error on parameter estimates? then `se = result.bse`; you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31523921).)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you try to save what a function is returning, in this case you expect three values. One for `fc`, one for `se` and one for `conf`. The problem is that the function `.forecast()` returns the prediction as a single object. You try to unpack a single object, but Python expects three. Therefore, “too many values to unpack…”. You can read the documentation of the function here to check what it returns:

https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.forecast.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.forecast

[image]

https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResults.html

If you try this it will save all predictions in the object “preds” as a pandas Series:

`preds = result.forecast(step)`

Secondly, if you want to know what a function is returning, you can simply write only the function (without … = function()) as the last line of a cell, then you can see what the function returns. Or you can check the documentation. You can print the object’s type with `print(type(result))`, it will return “statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMAResultsWrapper” and if you google you get to the documentation above.