# Python: error while performing bootstrap with scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, parameter-passing, curve-fitting

Having two datasets which apparently follow an exponential trend, I've fitted a curve into them by means of `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()`. The `x` dataset contains no zero and is bounded `0<x<=100`, while the `y` dataset is bounded `0<=y<=1`. This is the fitted equation:

```
def func(x, a, c, d):
    return a * numpy.exp(-c*x)+d
```

and I've called `curve_fit` like this:

```
popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = curve_fit(func, x1, y1, p0 = (1, 1e-6, 1), full_output=True)
```

where `x1` and `y1` are my two datasets. Now, [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581358/getting-standard-errors-on-fitted-parameters-using-the-optimize-leastsq-method-i), I wanted to perform the [Bootstrap Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) to make sure I obtained the standard errors on fitted parameters, which I will use to quantify the goodness-of-fit.

[Based on the code provided in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581358/getting-standard-errors-on-fitted-parameters-using-the-optimize-leastsq-method-i), given that apparently SciPy does not include anything of the kind, I've made a call to the Bootstrap Method like this:

```
pfit, perr = fit_bootstrap(pstart, xx, yy, func)
```

where `pfit` are the new fitting parameters (to be compared with those given by `curve_fit`), and `perr` are the standard errors I am after. `p-start` in my case is (1, 1e-6,1), `xx` are the x values used to plot the functions, and `yy` are the y values coming out of the fitted equation applied to the `xx` values. Lastly, the fitted function is `func=a*numpy.exp(-c*x)+d`.

**The call raises an error:** `TypeError: func() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)`. I understand there is a mismatch in terms of arguments, but I don't get the exact point where the fault is. Can anyone please help with this?

**Traceback:**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
in <module>()
    163     return pfit_bootstrap, perr_bootstrap
    164 
--> 165 pfit, perr = fit_bootstrap(pstart, xx, yy, func)
    166 
    167 print("\nFit parameters and parameter errors from bootstrap method :")

in fit_bootstrap(p0, datax, datay, function, yerr_systematic)
    127 
    128     # Fit first time
--> 129     pfit, perr = optimize.leastsq(errfunc, p0, args=(datax, datay), full_output=0)
    130 
    131 

in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    375     if not isinstance(args, tuple):
    376         args = (args,)
--> 377     shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
    378     m = shape[0]
    379     if n > m:

in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
     24 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
     25                 output_shape=None):
---> 26     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
     27     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
     28         if (output_shape[0] != 1):

in <lambda>(p, x, y)
    124 def fit_bootstrap(p0, datax, datay, function, yerr_systematic=0.0):
    125 
--> 126     errfunc = lambda p, x, y: function(x,p) - y
    127 
    128     # Fit first time

TypeError: func() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following line you should not pass the func as an argument:

```
pfit, perr = fit_bootstrap(pstart, xx, yy, func)
```

If you check the answer you referred to, they pass function named ff. The ff is defined as:

```
def ff(x, p):
    return func(x,*p)
```

once you added the definition of "ff", you can change the call to:

```
pfit, perr = fit_bootstrap(pstart, xx, yy, ff)
```

Comment: ok, but why is this? Why can't the `func` be an argument outright?