# How to go from standard deviation to standard error in python least_squares fit?

Tags: python, error-handling, statistics, curve-fitting, least-squares

I am not proficient in statistics. Following a thread: [How to compute standard deviation errors with scipy.optimize.least_squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388139/how-to-compute-standard-deviation-errors-with-scipy-optimize-least-squares), I got my std to be

```
std = np.sqrt(np.diagonal(np.linalg.inv(J.T @ J) * (res_lsq.fun.T @ res_lsq.fun / (res_lsq.fun.size - res_lsq.x.size))))
```

where

```
J = res_lsq.jac
```

My question now is how do I go from std to standard error? I know SE = STD/sqrt(N), but what is N in this case, is it simply number of datapoints ie

```
res_lsq.fun.size
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: STD/sqrt(N) this is applicable for Monte Carlo, where N is number of samples. Not sure if it works for you

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14857441/803359) might give some insight. One point is the reduced form used internally. And the the Jacobian is hidden in the error propagation (e.g. [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/general-linear-regression-nikolai-mikuszeit/) )