# How the least square method work with a given function

Tags: python, numpy, math

I have some data and I have used below numpy function to make the fitting. The fitting was fine but I need some explanation how it works.  What does p[1],p[2],p[0] stands for.It will be nice if I get the mathematical expression for that. what actually the least square is doing?

```
fitfuncvx = lambda p, x: p[2]+p[0]*np.exp(-x/p[1])
errfuncvx = lambda p, x, y: y - fitfuncvx(p, x)
sig_fit=np.where(Sig<12)
pinit = [1, 100,0.1]
pfinal, success = optimize.leastsq(errfuncvx, pinit[:], args=(Sig[sig_fit], vx[sig_fit]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What are `p[0], p[1], p[2]`?**

The `scipy.optimize` functions typically return an array of parameters `p`.  For example, given a linear equation:

[image]

`p` includes the intercept and successive coefficients (or weights) of a linear equation:

[image]

Thus in the latter example, `p[0]` and `p[1]` pertain to an *intercept* and *slope* of a line respectively.  Of course more parameters (`...`) can be optimized as well for higher order polynomials. The OP uses an exponential function, where the parameters can be rewritten as follows:

```
def fitfuncvx(p, x):
    b0, b1, b2 = p
    return b2 + b0*np.exp(-x/b1)
```

We see the parameters in `p` are explicitly unpacked into separate weights `b0, b1, b2`, which directly correspond with `p[0], p[1], p[2]` respectively.

---

**Details: How optimizers work?**

The first returned value of the [`scipy.optimize.leastsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html) function is an array of optimized fitted parameters, started from your initial guess, that is computed by iteratively minimizing residuals.  The residual is the distance between the predicted response (or `y`-hat value) and the true response (`y`).  The second returned value is a covariance matrix, from which one can [estimate the error in the calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581358/getting-standard-errors-on-fitted-parameters-using-the-optimize-leastsq-method-i).

For reference, I include the first three arguments of the `leastsq` signature:

```
scipy.optimize.leastsq(func, x0, args=(), ...)
```

- `func` is the objective function you wish to optimize
- `x0` is the initial guessed parameter
- `args` are additional variables required by the objective function (if any)

Answer (score 0):

The values `p[0], p[1], and p[2]` are coefficients being solved for in the least squares fit.

The least squares fit is calculating the values of the coefficients that minimize the sum of squared errors between the dependent variable data values and those predicted by the fitted function.

It's probably using a conjugate gradient iterative method to calculate the coefficients given a starting guess.

I don't think you should have a `p[2]`.

Your fit function should be:

```
y = c0*exp(-c1*x)
```

If I take the natural logarithm of both sides:

```
ln(y) = ln(c0) - c1*x = z
```

if you do that transformation you're doing a simple linear regression on a new function `z = z(x)`.

That's an easy problem.  There are [formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html) for the coefficients for the case of one independent variable.

Solve for the coefficients using your transformed data and substitute back into the original equation.

Comment: pinit values are for po, p1 and p2 as a initial guess?

Comment: I think so.  You should be reading the numpy docs more carefully.