# scipy.optimize.leastsq in Python not returning covariance matrix when fitting data

Tags: python, curve-fitting, least-squares, scipy-optimize, covariance-matrix

I am using optimize.leastsq to fit the data I have collected from a Mossbauer Spectroscopy experiment. The data was successfully fit, and the best fit parameters returned are good. But the second output cov_x, as called in the documentation, is given as an integer of 1, when I imagine that I am supposed to get a matrix. Why is this happening and how do I get the correct matrix?

Edit: @slothrop clarified that the output that I thought was cov_x is actually ier, an integer representing an error. 1 stands for ["Both actual and predicted relative reductions in the sum of squares\n  are at most %f" % ftol, None]. Could anyone help me understand what this means?

Edit 2: Solved. @slothrop politely informed me that I have to pass the parameter full_output=1 in order for optimize.leastsq to return cov_x.

P.S. I don't want to use optimize.curve_fit because I want to pass the parameters to my model function as a list rather than individual variables.

documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html

Here is my code. Parts of it may seem unnecessary due to my wanting to generalize to arbitrary start, stop points.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize, signal

# sample of data

x = np.array([100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179])
y = np.array([17714, 17582, 17377, 17292, 17210, 17248, 16667, 16479, 16609, 16461, 16584, 16898, 17033, 17162, 17231, 17349, 17420, 17762, 17650, 17511, 17607, 17525, 17818, 17628, 17576, 17576, 17865, 17963, 18005, 17860, 17769, 17935, 17829, 17770, 17847, 17855, 18085, 18123, 17706, 17790, 17766, 17864, 17864, 18094, 17826, 17662, 17693, 17767, 17905, 17805, 17738, 17812, 17690, 17722, 17747, 17679, 17763, 17405, 17570, 17396, 17291, 16892, 16727, 16797, 17003, 17180, 17245, 17436, 17565, 17388, 17522, 17504, 17715, 17585, 17782, 17652, 17736, 17897, 17766, 17789])


def lorentz(x, xpeak, linewidth, intensity):    # parameters: xpeak, linewidth, intensity
    return -intensity*(linewidth/2)**2/((x-xpeak)**2+(linewidth/2)**2)

def curve_fit(start,stop):
    
    xp_est = signal.find_peaks(-y[start:stop], width=5, height=-17250)[0]    # parameter estimates
    xp_est = start + xp_est
    npeaks = np.size(xp_est)
    lw_est = np.full(npeaks,7)
    I_est = (17800-y[xp_est])
    estimates = [xp_est, lw_est, I_est]
        
    def model(x, par):    # sum of lorentz distributions of peaks
        
        xpeak = par[:npeaks]
        linewidth = par[npeaks:2*npeaks]
        intensity = par[2*npeaks:]
        
        lorentz_sum = 17800
        for i in range(npeaks):
            lorentz_sum = lorentz_sum + lorentz(x,xpeak[i],linewidth[i],intensity[i])
        return lorentz_sum
    
    def residual(par, x, y):     
        return y - model(x, par)
    
    par, cov = optimize.leastsq(residual, estimates, (x[start:stop], y[start:stop]))
    plt.plot(x[start:stop], y[start:stop], '.', markersize=2)
    plt.plot(x[start:stop], model(x[start:stop], par))
    
    return par, cov

par, cov = curve_fit(0, 80)
print(par, type(par))
print(cov, type(cov))
plt.show()
```

Output

```
[ 162.67354556  108.5074825     5.99266549    7.74311055 1048.1092175
 1361.99804297] <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
1 <class 'int'>
[link]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixqql.png

Comment: Where's the printout?

Comment: I see five outputs described in the docs, not 2

Comment: Printout provided. Also there are only two outputs as far as I know. I tried asking for three and it said it was too many.

Comment: What is the value of `par` returned by `optimize.leastsq`?

Comment: The source code (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.10.0/scipy/optimize/_minpack_py.py#L282-L495) suggests that you need to pass the param `full_output=1` in order to get `cov_x` in the output.  With the default `full_output=0`, the result is the 2-tuple `(retval[0], info)` where `info` is an integer status code between 0 and 8. (I didn't find this obvious when looking only at the docs.)

Comment: @ slothrop Could you elaborate please? What do you mean by "pass the param full_output=1"? Thanks.

Comment: Oh I see. The output is ier, an integer, not cov_x. 1 means ["Both actual and predicted relative reductions in the sum of squares\n  are at most %f" % ftol, None]. Could anyone help decode what this means?

Comment: I'm no expert on this algorithm, but see: https://scipy-user.scipy.narkive.com/PoaDGSfh/least-squares-error-message - "this message means that the algorithm terminated
normally".

Comment: But I still don't have a covariance matrix. Also I found another question that addresses this issue, with no clear answer though.

Comment: @William Han what if you pass the parameter `full_output=1` when you call `optimize.leastsq`? Going by the source code, `cov_x` should be the second element of the returned tuple in that case.

Comment: Wow it really was that easy ‍♂️ Thanks so much @slothrop. I now have cov_x, and I followed the example given at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581358/getting-standard-errors-on-fitted-parameters-using-the-optimize-leastsq-method-i to get the covariances of my parameters.

Comment: @slothrop. The docs are really unclear on this, so I made a PR to change the wording a bit: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/17883

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it only outputs the result (1d array) and an integer flag (the integer number you got). If you want the full output, use this:

```
x0, cov, info, msg, status = optimize.leastsq(residual, estimates, (x[start:stop], y[start:stop]), full_output=True)
```

`cov` is what you want

You have to pass the `full_output=True` parameter in the `leastsq()` function