# Uncertainty of optimized parameters using the scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize, model-fitting, uncertainty

The aim is fitting the following equation by optimizing the K's parameters and knowing L:

```
Y_fit = (Ka*Kb**L2) / (1 + K11*L + Ka*Kb*L**2)
```

and Y = experimental points that one want to be fitted using the customized formula above with the optimized K0 parameters.

where

```py
K0 = array([Ka, Kb])

parameters_opt = op.minimize(np.square(Y_exp - Y_fit).sum(), K0, args=args, bounds=bounds, method="L-BFGS-B", tol=1e-6)
```

where args =  Extra arguments passed to the objective function and its derivatives

In all previous Q&A there is discussed the tolerance parameter (tol) and so on, but I could not find any final answer how to determine the uncertainty of those parameters for the fitting in order to give a final result of the K0 parameters such as:

Ka = x1 ± ∆x1

Kb = x2 ± ∆x2

(To complement the \Chi^2 of the fitting to evaluate the Goodness of my fitting).

Comment: [Is this answer helpful?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21844726/9453914). Goes in depth about fit error estimations, and suggests a few alternatives to setting up the least squares and solving with `minimize` yourself which have some conveniences you may find helpful.