# Least square optimization with bounds using scipy.optimize

Tags: python, numpy, mathematical-optimization

I have a least square optimization problem that I need help solving. So far, I have some code that does the following function:

```
shankarFunc = lambda p, x: p[0] * (1 - np.exp(-1 * ((x / p[1]) ** p[2])))
errFunc = lambda p, x, y: shankarFunc(p, x) - y

x0 = [max(y), 100 / max(y), 1]

p1, success = optimize.leastsq(errFunc, x0, args=(x, y))
```

and this *almost* works for all cases. It doesn't converge for some data, so I need to do a least square fitting **with** bounds for the fitted parameters. I then noticed that optimize.minimize has bounds, and tried to use that instead (minimizing the error function).

```
shankarFunc = lambda p, x: p[0] * (1 - np.exp(-1 * ((x / p[1]) ** p[2])))
errFunc = lambda p, x, y: shankarFunc(p, x) - y

x0 = [max(y), 100 / max(y), 1]
b0 = (0, max(y) + 2)
b1 = (1e-4, 5)
b2 = (0, None)
p1 = optimize.minimize(errFunc, x0, args=(x, y), bounds=(b0, b1, b2))
```

This gives me problems, as it returns the following error:

```
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 610, in
approx_fprime
    grad[k] = (f(*((xk + d,) + args)) - f0) / d[k]
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I've tried any number of variations on the input, but can't get rid of that.

How can I get optimize.minimize to play along? Is there a better solution to add bounds to the solution?

Comment: @veor perhaps this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16632712/832621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`minimize` optimizes a scalar function, you return an array (as it is excepted for `leastsq`). To use minizmize try change your function to:

```
errFunc = lambda p, x, y: np.sum((shankarFunc(p, x) - y)**2)
```

You could also use lmfit http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/ which allows to use leastsq with bound through transformations.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, I would suggest trying some or all of the following:

- Is your `errFunc` returning a scalar or a list/array? It also took me some time to get scipy.optimize.minimize to work, and looking at my code, my  error function returns a scalar.
- Make the optimisation method explicit so that it knows to use the bounds, e.g. `method='L-BFGS-B'`