# Forcing data to fit points with curve_fit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a little problem using the curve_fit function included in Scipy. Here is the function I would like to fit :

```
def funclog(x, a, b, c, d):
   return a * np.log(b * x + c) + d
```

The problem I have is that I would like the fit function to have a specific value on some points (y(min)=0 and y(max)=1). How can I force these points with curve_fit ?

Thank you

Comment: I believe [this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16632712/832621) will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement of the fit having specific values at `x=0`, `x=1`, implies that the parameters `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` are constrained according to the set of two equations:

`funclog(0, a, b, c, d) = 0`, `funclog(1, a, b, c, d) = 1`

For the form of `funclog` you are considering, you can solve this system of equations with respect to `a` and `d` resulting in the (unique) solution

`a = 1/(-log(c) + log(b + c))` and `d=log(c)/(log(c) - log(b + c))`

(assuming that `b` and `c` are such that the denominators are not equal to zero).

Replacing these expressions for `a` and `d` in `funclog` results in a new fitting function, namely,

`(log(c) - log(b*x + c))/(log(c) - log(b + c))`,

which by default satisfies the constraints. The values of `b` and `c` can be found by `curve_fit`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I looked for !

Answer (score 0):

You may try use bounds:

```
bounds = ([amin, bmin, cmin, dmin], [amax, bmax, cmax, dmax])
(or np.inf  -np.inf if limes of param is in infininty)
```

next

```
popt1, pcov1 = curve_fit(funclog, x, y, bounds=bounds)
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to bound my parameters but the result of the function itself

Comment: maybe you should try to "normalize" results after fitting?
You, know from max Y as 1 and min Y as zero?