# Python scipy - Line fit with a constraint of all points are above the line

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints, curve-fitting

I have the image below and, I would like to fit a line to the white points on the image. However, I have a constraint of all points should be above the line like in the last image. I have prepared the script below when no constraints are given. Can anybody help me with how do I refactor this code with the constraint of all points should be above the fitted line?

[image: input image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from scipy import optimize

def fit_line(img):

    def func_linear(x, x0, y0, k):
        # y=k(x−xo)+yo
        f = lambda x:k*(x-x0)+y0
        return f(x)

    points = np.where(img>0)
    points = np.array([points[1], points[0]]).T
    
    x = points[:,0]
    y = points[:,1]

    p0 = [1, 1, 1]
    p , e = optimize.curve_fit(func_linear, x, y, p0)

    pt1 = (np.min(x).astype(int), func_linear(np.min(x), *p).astype(int))
    pt2 = (np.max(x).astype(int), func_linear(np.max(x), *p).astype(int))

    cv2.line(img, pt1, pt2, (255,0,0), 3)


img = cv2.imread("toy_2.png")

fit_line(img)

plt.imshow(img)
```

[image: no constraint]

[image: with constraint]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shift the line along the y axis to ensure that all the points are above the line:

```
p[1] += np.max(y - func_linear(x, *p))
```

Result:

[image]

Full example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from scipy import optimize


def fit_line(img):
    def func_linear(x, x0, y0, k):
        # y=k(x−xo)+yo
        f = lambda x:k*(x-x0)+y0
        return f(x)

    points = np.where(img > 0)
    points = np.array([points[1], points[0]]).T

    x = points[:, 0]
    y = points[:, 1]

    p0 = [1, 1, 1]
    p, _ = optimize.curve_fit(func_linear, x, y, p0)

    # shift you line along the y axis
    p[1] += np.max(y - func_linear(x, *p)) + 1e-6  # use eps to ensure strictly greater

    pt1 = (np.min(x).astype(int), func_linear(np.min(x), *p).astype(int))
    pt2 = (np.max(x).astype(int), func_linear(np.max(x), *p).astype(int))

    cv2.line(img, pt1, pt2, (255, 0, 0), 3)


img = cv2.imread("toy_2.png")

fit_line(img)
plt.imshow(img)
```

You can also consider using adding a penalization term but it is more difficult to ensure that **all** points will be strictly above the line. Please see similar question:
[How do I put a constraint on SciPy curve fit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541171/how-do-i-put-a-constraint-on-scipy-curve-fit)